# CouchDB reducing sums with date filter

Tags: couchdb

I'm pretty new to couchdb and map/reduce in general. I have the following view:

```
{
  "_id": "_design/keys",
  "views": {
    "keys": {
      "map": "function(doc) { for (var thing in doc) { if (doc.created_at != null) { emit([thing, doc.created_at],1); } } }",
      "reduce": "function(key,values) { return sum(values); }"
    }
  }        
}
```

This works well to give me a sum of the count of all document keys in the database with the proper group_level:

```
.../_design/keys/_view/keys?group_level=1

{"rows":[
  {"key":["_id"],"value":2},
  {"key":["_rev"],"value":2},
  {"key":["created_at"],"value":2},
  {"key":["testing"],"value":2}
 ]}
```

Now what I want to do is reduce these mapped documents by date, which is an IOS8601 string:

```
  {"rows":[
    {"key":["_id","2015-11-25T21:13:58Z"],"value":1},
    {"key":["_id","2015-11-25T21:14:39Z"],"value":1},
    {"key":["_rev","2015-11-25T21:13:58Z"],"value":1},
    {"key":["_rev","2015-11-25T21:14:39Z"],"value":1},
    {"key":["created_at","2015-11-25T21:13:58Z"],"value":1},
    {"key":["created_at","2015-11-25T21:14:39Z"],"value":1},
    {"key":["testing","2015-11-25T21:13:58Z"],"value":1},
    {"key":["testing","2015-11-25T21:14:39Z"],"value":1}
  ]}
```

But I still want the results grouped by the first part of the key. That is, I want to specify a start time of `2015-11-25T21:13:57Z` and an end time of `2015-11-25T21:13:59Z`, and get back everything with the time stamp of `2015-11-25T21:13:58Z`, like so:

```
{"rows":[
  {"key":["_id"],"value":1},
  {"key":["_rev"],"value":1},
  {"key":["created_at"],"value":1},
  {"key":["testing"],"value":1}
 ]}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You should use your view function to emit the date component of the timestamp (which as you note is conveniently already in hierarchical structure) as a complex key:

Instead of "2015-11-26T...", emit the key as [2015, 11, 26, 21, 13, 58]

Then you can range query on the complex keys to different levels (year, month, date, time). Note that if you use times other than Zulu time you may need to use the view function to read the tz and emit in Zulu time so that all sort correctly.

Please pardon typos as was entered from mobile device

Comment: this is super neat

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem just a few days ago and found that [List Functions](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/transforming.html) are a pretty easy way to solve this. You could simply use the date as key, the `things` as values, do the counting in the list function and can still use all the regular view features to define start and end keys.